# Disallow Set and Map to have unknown generics in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I noticed I forgot to add a generic for a `Set` in code I wrote a long time ago. It's typed as `Set<unknown>`. Surprisingly, this allows me to use all the `Set` methods without errors. With untyped arrays, it'll throw errors. E.g.:

```
const set = new Set();
set.has(1);

const map = new Map();
map.has(1);

const arr = []; // Variable 'arr' implicitly has type 'any[]' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.
arr.includes(1); // Variable 'arr' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.
```

How can I make Set and Map also throw errors if their types are unknown?

Comment: Your code doesn't demonstrate "if I type it as `unknown[]`"  Your `arr` is an auto-evolving array type which is implicitly of type `any[]`, which is an error because of `--noImplicitAny`.  It's not `unknown[]` at all.  If you actually had an array of type `unknown[]` there'd be no error there, either, as shown [in this Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mpKlMN).  Presumably you're trying to ask something about `Set` and `Map` but the array demonstration is distracting at best.  Could you [edit] to remove that entirely and demonstrate your issue in some other fashion?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35259 and you can follow up over the dupe target and linked discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest you can get in pure TypeScript, other than replacing/editing your local copies of [`lib.2015.collection.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3516ca96e552ba82c4c7d9215adba4afc53eeedc/src/lib/es2015.collection.d.ts) and [`lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3516ca96e552ba82c4c7d9215adba4afc53eeedc/src/lib/es2015.iterable.d.ts) to disallow calling `new Map()` and `new Set()` with no constructor arguments, is to [merge in your own declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) that cause such constructor calls to produce more unusable values, like `Map<never, never>` and `Set<never>`:

```
// declare global { // if in module scope

interface SetConstructor {
  new(): Set<never>
}

interface MapConstructor {
  new(): Map<never, never>;
}

// } // if in module scope
```

[The `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) is the opposite of [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).  No valid value is assignable to `never`.  So while the compiler will still let you construct such `Map`s and `Set`s, you'll get errors if you try to use them:

```
const map = new Map();
map.has(1); // error!
// ---> ~
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

const set = new Set();
set.has(1); // error! 
// ---> ~
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQGUoQMIHswDOEMArkhLjKgN7CqphQDuAFAJQBcGWAPIwG6wAfMAC+oSLEQpUAWQQAHPIWJkKVWvUatOcxXyiCYAGgaHhAbjHBgSfEVQEsqALxmm3COytOIAOgALBAIWAEY2C1QAeijUWBhKAEJUYBjUAFpMoVQAP1TYgEEYAHMSAFsoSFRcOFQIAE8FNAByMHKAI1hm1BACBlwIVGCCEGKwBHaAGzQKVAUEGAQK6CoausaWgS6-GzsVVDLFV3c9BW9gQ4VA4LCI6Nj4pPyMrNznotKKqrWGptRWjpdHp9MADIYEEZjCbTOq4OYLJZYWDVWq-TbmGDNHZAA)